# Publish over SSH invalid private key

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I use **Publish over SSH** in Jenkins to connect to remote server. I already have a private key(in OpenSSH format starts with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`) that works perfectly from shell under **jenkins user** but when I use it from web interface it throws
`jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to add SSH key. Message [invalid privatekey: [B@4bba7224]`

At the same time I generated another key on Jenkins machine (Debian GNU/Linux 9 in Docker) and copied `id_rsa.pub` to remote machine. This key is different and starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and for this key error is `Message [Auth fail]` so it understand the key.

Answer (score 6):

I just came across the same issue. The plugin was confused by the newer OpenSSH format (I also had a private key starting with `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`).

I saved the key and loaded it in PuTTyGen, then Conversions-> Export OpenSSH Key (notice there is a "Export OpenSSH Key (force new file format)" which we don't want. This is on Windows obviously; I'm not sure what equivalent would be on other OS'es.

My newly exported key started with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`and the plugin accepted it after this.

Answer (score 1):

You use this command to generate new keypem

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM
```

The keypem start with

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

sshCommand in Jenkins will accept this key

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(
    credentialsId: 'server', 
    usernameVariable: 'USER', 
    keyFileVariable: 'KEY_FILE'),
    string(credentialsId: 'server-ip', variable: 'EC2_IP')
]) {
    def remote = [:]
    remote.name = USER
    remote.host = EC2_IP
    remote.user = USER
    remote.identityFile = KEY_FILE
    remote.allowAnyHosts = true
    sshCommand remote: remote, command: "pwd"
}
```